# Free, lightweight image editor with easy to use text tool

Tags: windows, gratis, image-editor, image-editing

Especially important is the text tool. The text tool should be rather similar to Visio's text tool, but less than Paint.NET's or GIMP's. That means, text should be easily editable without having to manually create or select layers, something like an "implicit layer management".

I have already tested many image editors, but they either do not provide a good text tool or are so complex, that they do not start fast anymore.

**Requirements**

- Windows >= 7
- free of charge, no aggressive/annoying ads
- fast startup (mid-class notebook is about 5 years old), little resource usage (not like GIMP, more like MS Paint)
- support for common formats including JPEG and PNG
- crop, rotate, scale size
- text tool as described above: moveable, editable (preferably with live preview directly in the image)

**EDIT**

What I have already tested (sorted by descending preference):

- Hornil StylePix
- Pixlr
- Artweaver Free
- Ashampoo PhotoCommander 12
- PixBuilder Studio
- Toolwiz Pretty Photo
- Fotor
- Picasa
- Serif PhotoPlus Starter
- Krita
- MyPaint w32
- PhotoPad Foto-Editor

All of them support most of my requirements, but either their text tool is limited (text not easily moveable or editable, unhandy to use), their startup is too slow or they include things I do not want to have (e. g. Picasa imports all images found on my computer and I do not like software doing things automatically, which I do not really need).

The image viewer integrated in Windows 10 by default offers most of the required functionality but no text tool.

Comment: Do you need to be able to go back in and edit the text after save & exit? Most formats do not support this functionality so it would be nice to know if you do need it.

Comment: No. As soon as I have saved the image and closed the program I do not have to be able to edit it anymore. That would probably require a specific format like .psd, ... However, as long as I have not closed it I would like to be able to edit all text elements I inserted in this session.